# Why blinding integer $r$ needs to be co-prime with $N$ in blind RSA signature

Tags: rsa, blind-signature

According to blind RSA signature [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) the random value $r$ in $m^\prime=mr^e \bmod N$ needs to be relatively prime to $N$.

- Why is this a requirement?

A follow up a related question: after $s$ (unblinded signature) and $m$ (original message) are revealed, can *anyone* (and not only the signing authority) check the validity of the signature by checking $s^e=m \bmod N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this a requirement?

Well, if $r$ has (say) $p$ as a factor, then it makes the unblinding step rather difficult.

The original $m$ has $N = pq$ possible, as does $m^d$; if $r$ is a multiple of $p$, then $mr^e$ has only $q$ possible values; if we pass it to the signer, it'll come back to us with a value $m'^d$ that also has only $q$ possible values.  We cannot map $m'^d$ back to $m^d$ (as a single $m'^d$ value would map back to $p$ possible $m^d$ values, and we don't know which one it is.

> A follow up a related question: after $s$ (unblinded signature) and $m$ (original message) are revealed, can *anyone* (and not only the signing authority) check the validity of the signature by checking $s^e=m \bmod N$?

Yes, anyone with the public key can validate it.  This is generally true for public key signature algorithms.